# Script em Python não gera o gráfico como esperado

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Meu algoritmo em Python está rodando perfeitamente, só não consigo gerar o gráfico! Não consegui identificar o erro... O que tem de errado?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

va=float(input('Digite o valor a ser aplicado: '))
juros=1.05
inflacao=1.02
saque=25000
vaplicacao=[va]
nsaque=0
vsaque=[]

while saque<=vaplicacao[len(vaplicacao)-1]:
    va=(vaplicacao[len(vaplicacao)-1]*juros)-(saque)
    vaplicacao.append(va)
    nsaque=nsaque+1
    saque=saque*inflacao
    vsaque.append(nsaque)

plt.plot(vsaque,vaplicacao,'b-')
plt.title('Saldo x Saque')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Saque ao longo dos anos')
plt.ylabel('Saldo ao longo dos anos')
plt.show()
```

Comment: E quais são as entradas que está utilizando? Porque todos os testes que fiz obtive o erro "*ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes*".

Comment: Eu preciso que o gráfico mostre no eixo "X" o vetor "vsaque" e no eixo "Y" o vetor "vaplicacao". Este é o erro que aparece aqui.    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\EXERCÍCIO 5 LISTA 5.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.plot(vsaque,vaplicacao,'b-')
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3358, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Mas não estava rodando perfeitamente? Ficou confuso agora. Esse erro aparece para você também?

Comment: É que eu rodei o algorítimo sem as informações para gerar o gráfico e mandei ele dar um print no vetor "vsaque" e "vaplicacao". Com isso pude visualizar se o algorítimo estava calculando corretamente e está.. Agora eu preciso que ele gere um gráfico com esses vetores, só que quando inseri os códigos para gerar o gráfico aparece estes erros informados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso, como a contagem de saques é linear e sequencial, você não precisa montar uma lista para o eixo X do gráfico. A `matplotlib` é capaz de fazer isso automaticamente, e seu programa poderia ficar mais compacto, veja só:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

va = float(input('Digite o valor a ser aplicado: '))

juros = 1.05
inflacao = 1.02
saque = 25000
vaplicacao = [va]

while saque <= vaplicacao[-1]:
    va = (vaplicacao[-1] * juros) - saque
    saque *= inflacao
    vaplicacao.append(va)

plt.plot( vaplicacao, 'b-')
plt.plot( vaplicacao, 'ro')

plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Saldo x Saque')
plt.xlabel('Saque ao longo dos anos')
plt.ylabel('Saldo ao longo dos anos')

plt.show()
```

Saída (`va=800000`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída (`va=600000`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída (`va=400000`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você está inicializando a lista `vaplicacao` com um valor:

```
vaplicacao=[va]
```

Enquanto a lista `vsaque` inicia vazia:

```
vsaque=[]
```

Como, dentro do laço, você sempre adiciona um valor em cada lista, a lista `vaplicacao` **sempre** terá um elemento a mais que `vsaque`; assim, é impossível plotar em um gráfico uma curva que tenha `n` pontos no eixo das abcissas e `n+1` pontos no eixo das ordenadas. Se você iniciar `vsaque` com um valor possivelmente funcionará:

```
vsaque=[nsaque]
```

Aliás, para pegar o último elemento da lista, basta fazer `lista[-1]`; não precisa de `lista[len(lista)-1]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

va = float(input('Digite o valor a ser aplicado: '))
juros = 1.05
inflacao = 1.02
saque = 25000
vaplicacao = [va]
nsaque = 0
vsaque = [nsaque]

while saque <= vaplicacao[-1]:
    va = vaplicacao[-1]*juros - saque
    vaplicacao.append(va)
    nsaque += 1
    saque = saque*inflacao
    vsaque.append(nsaque)

plt.plot(vsaque, vaplicacao, 'b-')
plt.title('Saldo x Saque')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Saque ao longo dos anos')
plt.ylabel('Saldo ao longo dos anos')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou, comecei a lista vsaque=[nsaque]... Muito Obrigado!